# Passing & Reading String Arrays to C DLL Procedures

Tags: c, arrays, string, dll, dllexport

This DLL procedure receives an array of strings and simply returns the size of the array based on the number of null terminations found:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int sendStrings(char charArray[])
{
    char* p = charArray;
    for (; *p != '\0'; ++p)
    {
        //MessageBox(NULL, LPTSTR(charArray), TEXT("DLL"), 0);
    }
    int arraySize = p - charArray;
    return arraySize;
}
```

How could I assign each one of those individual null-terminated strings to separate string variables in the procedure.

Alternatively, is there a better way of passing arrays of strings to such a DLL procedure?

The C# calling routine:

```
List<string> strArr = new List<string>();
strArr.Add("first");
strArr.Add("second");
strArr.Add("third");

sendStrings(strArr.ToArray());
```

How could the DLL break the strings up *(first, second, third)*?

Comment: please post how charArray[] is defined.  What is being passed to this function?  what is the current output?  what is the expected output?

Comment: if it were me..  pass `char **charArray`  and have the last entry in the top level array be NULL.  Very similar to the char *argv[] parameter to main()

Comment: Added the calling code...

Comment: I guess you should look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317931/marshal-an-array-of-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-code-using-p-invoke