# Convert string[] to a double pointer in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

I'm trying to hand a `string[]` as `byte**` from C# to C++. I have to say, as a disclaimer, that I never really worked with C++ or pointers before. So I may get some things wrong. I encode and pin every `string` with a code like this:

```cs
var strings = new string[] { "Some string", "Another string" };
var handles = new GCHandle[string.Length];
var pointers = new byte*[string.Length];

for (int index = 0; index < strings.Length; index++)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strings[index]);
    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    handles[index] = handle;
    pointers[index] = (byte*)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();
}

//Release the handles later...
```

The problem I'm currently having is, that I can't pin the array that contains all the pointers. I tried to use

```cs
GCHandle.Alloc(pointers, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

which throws an exception and

```cs
fixed (byte** pointer = &pointers[0])
```

won't work, because the array is unfixed outside the `fixed` block. So I thought I could maybe do something like this

```cs
byte** pointer = (byte**)this.pointers[0]
```

to obtain a pointer, which results in an exception, because I'm trying to read/write protected memory.

I'm currently unsure if it's even possible to accomplish, or if my approach is just wrong. Does anybody has a idea or was in a similar situation?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Marshal an array of strings from C# to C code using p/invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317931/marshal-an-array-of-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-code-using-p-invoke)

Comment: If the target language is C++, the title should reflect this, please.

Comment: Technically C++ is *NOT* a super-set o f C, none-the-less most C will run in C++